# SQL Server : varchar to Date Conversion/Casting Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I use this

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '26/03/2014', 101)
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But if I use this

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '26/03/2014', 103)
```

There's no error and this is the result returned:

```
2014-03-26
```

I don't understand why the first code is not working, as far as I searched and understand is that `101` is for US date and `103` is for UK/French Date.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu .. Im using MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '26/03/2014', 101)
```

will be interpreted in the US way (`mm/dd/yyyy`) : the 26th month, 3rd day of 2014 - this obviously fails (no 26th month).

This however:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '26/03/2014', 103)
```

will be interpreted the European way (`dd/mm/yyyy`): the 26th day of the 3rd month (March) of 2014.

You need to **very careful** with parsing strings to date! [Check out all the defined *styles* for `CONVERT` here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

If you want to be sure it works always, use the **ISO-8601** format: `YYYYMMDD` or in your case:

```
SELECT CAST('20140326' AS DATE)
```

will **always** work, no matter what language/regional settings you have

Comment: @Tauseef: yes - that's what the ISO-8601 format defines

Answer (score 3):

Thats becuase of the [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)(101) which you are using.

```
101 is mm/dd/yyyy
```

So 26 cannot be a month. Hence resulting in error.

```
103 is dd/mm/yy
```

And hence it is working correctly. if the day would have been less than 13, it would have taken it as month and there would be logical error.

Answer (score 1):

The convert signature is as follows
`CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)`

for the date conversion, the styles are as follows

```
101 mm/dd/yy    USA

103 dd/mm/yy    British/French
```

more formats here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use language neutral date representations for literals. In case with style 101, SQL Server assumed the MM/dd/yyyy instead of dd/MM/yyyy.

Here's a nice link with more info from MVP Tibor Karaszi:

http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes